# Is there a way to use the ViewModel data in Same type of fragments but different instance with different API response?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have integrate my project structure in MVVM,

Right now the project has MainActivity and MainFragment.
MainActivity invokes the MainFragment and MainFragment handles the Top menu as viewpager.
I have implemented an commond Menu screen(Fragment) which used in each menu.

The common menu screen uses MainViewModel and also mainfragment uses the MainViewModel.
Each of the menu screen is separated with each different instance.
Inside the MainViewModel, livedata model is there and which is getting observed by each menu screen.
The livedata update whenever different API response comes for each menu screen.

My issue is whenever any API response comes then each menu screen receive event for change.
Instead for each of the screen there should be different livedata. I have kept the common livedata and MainViewModel because all the menus and each fragments are dynamically added.

Can anyone when using the same viewmodel how different livedata can be used?
Because as I said the livedata type is common for each menu fragment?

For reference giving the code snippet below:

// This is the common mainViewModel for each menu
mainViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new MainViewModelFactory())
mainViewModel.getPageResult().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer() {

}

Thanks
Cheers

I have researched on Shared view model but doesn't feel that would resolve this issue.

Comment: You should post code that illustrates the problem. Your high-level description is open to interpretation and miscommunication.